# Is there an easy way to trim the last three characters off a string

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
var a = "abcdefg";
var b = "xxxxxxxx";
```

The strings are always longer than five characters.

Now I need to trim off the last 3 characters. Is there some simple way that I can do this with C#?

Comment: Which is it? Four or three? You're title and question body are different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the trivial case you can just use

```
result = s.Substring(0, s.Length-3);
```

to remove the last three characters from the string.

Or as Jason suggested `Remove` is an alternative:

```
result = s.Remove(s.Length-3)
```

---

Unfortunately for unicode strings there can be a few problems:

- A unicode codepoint can consist of multiple `char`s since the encoding of string is UTF-16 (See Surrogate pairs). This happens only for characters outside the basic plane, i.e. which have a code-point >2^16. This is relevant if you want to support Chinese.
- A glyph (graphical symbol) can consist of multiple codepoints. For example `ä` can be written as `a` followed by a combining `¨`.
- Behavior with right-to-left writing might not be what you want either

Answer (score 4):

You want [String.Remove(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx)

> Deletes all the characters from this string beginning at a specified
>   position and continuing through the last position.

If you want to perform validation, along the lines of druttka's answer, I would suggest creating an extension method

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
  public static string SafeRemove(this string s, int numCharactersToRemove)
  {
    if (numCharactersToRemove > s.Length)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("numCharactersToRemove");
    }

    // other validation here

    return s.Remove(s.Length - numCharactersToRemove);
  }
}

var s = "123456";
var r = s.SafeRemove(3); //r = "123"
var t = s.SafeRemove(7); //throws ArgumentException
```

Comment: +1 Substring will do it, but why not use the right tool for the job?

Comment: It's important to note that since string is immutable this does not modify the original string but returns the modified string.

Answer (score 2):

```
string a = "abcdefg";
a = a.Remove(a.Length - 3);
```

Comment: maybe you need to assign the result back to `a`?  `a = a.Remove(a.Length - 3);`

Comment: @Bazzz you're right of course - string is immutable. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
string newString = oldString.Substring(0, oldString.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need to trim off the last 3 characters, you can do this

```
string a = "abcdefg";
if (a.Length > 3)
{
  a = a.Substring(0, a.Length-3);
}
else
{
  a = String.Empty;
}
```